# Highcharts changing X axis Interval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have added Highcharts to my rails app and I can get the daily average memory usage of the servers I am monitoring.  Is there away to make this dynamic down to the minute or how can I alter the x axis to give me averages per minute rather than per day as it is at present.

The index.html.erb is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: "memory_chart"
    },
    title: {
      text: "Free Virtual Memory"
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: "datetime"
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: "MBytes"
      }
    },

    series: [
    <%  { "Server1" => ServerMemory.Server1, "Server2" => ServerMemory.Server2, "Server3" => ServerMemory.Server3, "Server4" => ServerMemory.Server4, "Server5" => ServerMemory.Server5}.each do |name, items| %>
    {
      name: "<%= name %>",
      pointInterval: <%= 24.hours * 1000%>,
      pointStart: <%= 1.week.ago.to_i * 1000%>,
      data: <%= (1.week.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| items.total_on(date).to_f}.inspect %>
    }, 
<% end %>
    ]
  })
})
</script>
<h1>Listing server_memories</h1>
 <div id="memory_chart" style="width:560px; height:300px;"></div>
<h4><%= will_paginate @ServerMemory %></h4>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Servername</th>
      <th>Ipaddress</th>
      <th>Freevirtualmemory</th>
      <th>Freephysicalmemory</th>
      <th>Totalvirtualmemory</th>
      <th>Totalphysicalmemory</th>
      <th>Created at</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @server_memories.each do |server_memory| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= server_memory.serverName %></td>
        <td><%= server_memory.IPAddress %></td>
        <td><%= server_memory.freeVirtualMemory %></td>
        <td><%= server_memory.freePhysicalMemory %></td>
        <td><%= server_memory.totalVirtualMemory %></td>
        <td><%= server_memory.totalPhysicalMemory %></td>
        <td><%= server_memory.created_at %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<h4><%= will_paginate @ServerMemory %></h4>
```

The Model is as follows.

```
class ServerMemory < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :Server1, where(:IPAddress => "192.168.10.180")
    scope :Server2, where(:IPAddress => "192.168.10.102")
    scope :Server3, where(:IPAddress => "192.168.10.150")
    scope :Server4, where(:IPAddress => "192.168.10.5")
    scope :Server5, where(:IPAddress => "192.168.10.100")
    def self.total_on(date)
        where("date(updated_at) = ?", date).average(:freeVirtualMemory)
    end
end
```

Below is a small snapshot of the data from the MYSQL table.

```
+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| IPAddress      | freevirtualmemory | updated_at          |
+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 192.168.10.5   |           3796108 | 2014-03-31 15:38:21 |
| 192.168.10.102 |           3764768 | 2014-03-31 15:36:56 |
| 192.168.10.102 |           3764752 | 2014-03-31 15:36:33 |
| 192.168.10.150 |           3025972 | 2014-03-31 15:36:26 |
| 192.168.10.100 |           2551800 | 2014-03-31 15:36:16 |
| 192.168.10.180 |           1319428 | 2014-03-31 15:36:04 |
| 192.168.10.102 |           3764996 | 2014-03-31 15:30:56 |
| 192.168.10.102 |           3765312 | 2014-03-31 15:30:32 |
| 192.168.10.150 |           3026096 | 2014-03-31 15:30:25 |
| 192.168.10.100 |           2552092 | 2014-03-31 15:30:14 |
| 192.168.10.180 |           1318260 | 2014-03-31 15:30:02 |
| 192.168.10.180 |           1302356 | 2014-03-31 13:57:45 |
| 192.168.10.102 |           3764748 | 2014-03-31 13:55:45 |
| 192.168.10.150 |           3024952 | 2014-03-31 13:54:21 |
| 192.168.10.100 |           2550668 | 2014-03-31 13:54:10 |
| 192.168.10.180 |           1301892 | 2014-03-31 13:52:10 |
| 192.168.10.102 |           3764672 | 2014-03-31 13:50:10 |
| 192.168.10.150 |           3024820 | 2014-03-31 13:48:16 |
| 192.168.10.100 |           2550732 | 2014-03-31 13:48:06 |
| 192.168.10.180 |           1310068 | 2014-03-31 13:46:05 |
| 192.168.10.102 |           3764692 | 2014-03-31 13:44:05 |
| 192.168.10.150 |           3024928 | 2014-03-31 13:42:11 |
```

Comment: Simply get minutes averages from server and then set pointInterval to one minute (if I understand you correctly).

Comment: You understand it correctly but when I change the points interval to 1 minute or 1 hour the query to the database does not change.

Comment: The SQL query I see going to the DB is as follows.  I think the issue might be with the (1.week.ago.to_date..Date.today).map statement but if I try to change to datetime, I get "can't iterate from DateTime." SELECT AVG(`server_memories`.`freeVirtualMemory`) AS avg_id FROM `server_memories` WHERE `server_memories`.`IPAddress` = '192.168.10.180' AND (date(updated_at) = '2014-03-25')

Comment: When I change the pointsinterval I see the chart x axis scale change the data being displayed to not change

Comment: Changing the chart options won't have anything to do with changing the database query...you need to do that separately.

Comment: @jlbriggs has right - changing something in Highcharts won't change anything in your backend. Rails generate code when page is loaded, after that you have no access to Rails (until user reload page). Use AJAX to load new data to Highcharts.